# Default vt number at Linux startup

Tags: linux, console

Whenever we boot into linux, then the default vt used by the kernel is 1.
And X starts either on vt2 or on vt7. We can switch back to vt1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to see the logs or messages.

Is there any way to start booting in any other vt but not in vt1?
Will it be kernel-space or user-space?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *start booting in any other VT but not in VT1*? Are you asking about what device is bound to the [system console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_console)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a kernel change.  The active kernel virtual terminal number is initialized to zero (i.e. the first virtual terminal, `vt1`) in the `con_init()` function in the kernel.

You can of course change the active kernel virtual terminal after bootstrap with the `chvt` command.  But *starting* the bootstrap with a different active kernel virtual terminal cannot be done from userspace.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[linux-vt](http://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/linux-vt.xml)".  *Devices*.  nosh toolset.